# Prove that $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx$ is a factor of $(x-y)^n+(y-z)^n+(z-x)^n$, if $n$ is not divisible by 3.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx$ is a factor of $(x-y)^n+(y-z)^n+(z-x)^n$, if $n$ is not divisible by 3.

Here $n = 3m + 1$ or $n = 3m + 2$ for some integer $m$. RHS is a huge expression. 
I have no idea to prove it. please help me to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if  $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity, then 
$$x^2+y^2+z^2 - xy - yz - zx = (x+y\omega + z\omega^2)(x+y\omega^2 + z\omega)$$
Thus it is sufficient to prove that $x+y\omega + z\omega^2$ divides the given expression when $n$ is not a multiple of 3. Now, when $x+y\omega + z\omega^2 = 0$, then 
\begin{align*}
(x-y)^n + (y-z)^n + (z-x)^n &= (-y\omega - z\omega^2 - y)^n + (y-z)^n + (z + y\omega + z\omega^2)^n \\
&= (y\omega^2 - z\omega^2)^n + (y-z)^n + (y\omega - z\omega)^n \\
&= (y-z)^n (1 + \omega^n + \omega^{2n}) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
when $n$ is not a multiple of 3. Thus $x + y\omega + z\omega^2$ divides the given expression when $n$ is not a multiple of 3. A similar proof shows that $x + y\omega^2 + z\omega$ also divides the given expression when $n$ is not a multiple of 3. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks, but is it not necessary to show that for $n=3m$, the expression  $(x-y)^n+(y-z)^n+(z-x)^n\neq 0$

Comment: When $n$ is a multiple of 3, the proof shows that the remainder when the expression is divided by $x + y\omega + z\omega^2$ is $3(y-z)^n$ and hence is not zero.